# Export of Wikipedia page as BibLaTeX?

Tags: wikipedia

In the english [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/), you'll find via the page `Tools` menu an article related page "Cite this page" menu entry.  (This is also true to other Wikipedia language sites, such as the german de.wikipedia.org site.)

Clicking the "Cite that page" menu, will open an associated page.  On that page, the basic bibliographic data of that particular article are listed, as well as some suggestions, on how to cite that page, following different citation style guidelines.  The page also offers two slightly different BibTeX code blocks, to be copied into your personal `.bib` files.

E.g. see this "[Cite this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:CiteThisPage&page=Biber_%28LaTeX%29&id=1116502991&wpFormIdentifier=titleform)" on the Biber page.

I consider neither of the codes to be usefull BibTeX entries.  For example: the key `author` will always be set up with the value `Wikipedia contributors`.  This field should contain the names of the authors in the BibTeX syntax: `Name1, Firstname 1 AND Name2, Firstname2, AND ...`.
To make this value work, it must be grouped into another pair of curly braces, otherwise BibTeX would try to guess the Name and Firstname from that values.

Although, there is a dedicated page, which names all authors, I strongly recommend against listing them in that field.  That would be to confusing.  Instead, you should use the alternative key `editor`, which is of course Wikipedia, or, to be more precise, the Wikimedia Foundation.

The `title` key is made up of the actual page title (which is correct), but the editor ( `--- {Wikipedia}{,} The Free Encyclopedia`) is also added, which is not correct in this kind of key.  As suggested above, using the editor field, would solve both problems in one go.

Next comes the `year` key, which has the correct value, but Wikipedia also knows month, day and even time down to the second, when this page was created (i.e. last edited).  So the date information provided in this Copy&Paste blocks could be more precise also!

One of those code blocks include the key `url` which is unknown to BibTeX and will hence be ignored.  The other block uses the `howpublished` key instead.  Both feature the permanent link ID of the page in question, the latter one enclosed in a `\url{}` command.  This command is unknown to standard LaTeX, you have to provide it by loading one of the various packages, e.g. `url`, `hyperref`.

Next comes the key `note`, which contains information like `[Online; accessed 16-July-2023]`.  As BibTeX was invented before the WWW, this is a suitable workaround.  Nevertheless, the format of this date might interfer with other date information, present in the BibTeX databases of the person, downloading/copying that information.

Instead of offering two slightly different code blocks to be copied into your personal BibTeX databases, I'd love to have a code block, based on the more modern BibLaTeX package.

BibLaTeX offers a dedicated `@Online` type for this kind of bibliographical sources, which comes with various new keys, including `url` and `urldate`, which eliminates the need, to store those information via workaround in less suitable keys.  The `urldate`  expects the date to be given in the ISO format: `YYYY-MM-DD`, which, of course, could be easily generated from the page information present in the Wikipedia databases.

Also, using the `biblatex` package in your LaTeX documents, ensures, that package `hyperref` is loaded automatically, to provide the otherwise unknown `\url` command.

In my eyes, the Wikipedia should offer a state of the art block for BibLaTeX.  Staying with the example [biber](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:CiteThisPage&page=Biber_%28LaTeX%29&id=1116502991&wpFormIdentifier=titleform) page, mentioned above, the code block should look something like this:

```
@Online{en.wikipedia:biber,
  editor     = {{Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia}},
  title      = {Biber (LaTeX)},
  date       = {2022-10-16},
  url        = {https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Biber_(LaTeX)&oldid=1116502991},
  version    = 1116502991,
  organization   = {Wikimedia Foundation},
  urldate    = {2023-07-16},
  langid     = {english}
}
```

(I took freedom, to add the language information also.  You'll find it in the ID `en.wikipedia` and in the specialized key `langid` also.  The information used in this example are more or less copied 1:1 from the "Cite this page" info.  Only the value of the `urldate` was slightly modified.)

I twice tried to open a discussion in the german wikipedia discussion groups, the latest attempt being of may 2023.

The discussion did not get any response so far.

I hope, someone, who is able, to change some code lines or who knows someone, being able of doing that, will read this lines.

Comment: So... what is your question then? You gave delicate details on why you think Wikipedia's BibLaTeX is not correct, but there is nothing answerable and on-topic for SO in your wall of text as far as I can see. If this is a bug report, the best place for it would be [Wikimedia's Phabricator](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/).

Comment: "I hope, someone, who is able, to change some code lines or who knows someone, being able of doing that, will read this lines." How many wikipedia responsibles will read this topic here? Shouldn't it be placed at wikipedia? SO does not have the code of wikipedia to change some lines.